# Preventing message loss with Kafka High Level Consumer 0.8.x

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

A typical kafka consumer looks like the following:

kafka-broker ---> kafka-consumer ----> downstream-consumer like Elastic-Search

And according to the documentation for [Kafka High Level Consumer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example):

> The ‘auto.commit.interval.ms’ setting is how often updates to the
>   consumed offsets are written to ZooKeeper

It seems that there can be message loss if the following two things happen:

1. Offsets are committed just after some messages are retrieved from kafka brokers.
2. Downstream consumers (say Elastic-Search) fail to process the most recent batch of messages OR the consumer process itself is killed.

It would perhaps be most ideal if the offsets are **not** committed automatically based on a time interval but they are committed by an API. This would make sure that the kafka-consumer can signal the committing of offsets only after it receives an acknowledgement from the downstream-consumer that they have successfully consumed the messages. There could be some replay of messages (if kafka-consumer dies before committing offsets) but there would at least be no message loss.

Please let me know if such an API exists in the High Level Consumer.

Note: I am aware of the Low Level Consumer API in 0.8.x version of Kafka but I do not want to manage everything myself when all I need is just one simple API in High Level Consumer.

Ref:

1. [AutoCommitTask.run()](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/d5b43b19bb06e9cdc606312c8bcf87ed267daf44/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerCoordinator.java#L408-L435), look for *commitOffsetsAsync*
2. [SubscriptionState.allConsumed()](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/5db2c99e15a4467489b495144815ac8334c2c5d4/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/SubscriptionState.java#L285-L293)

Answer (score 4):

There is a commitOffsets() API in the [High Level Consumer API](http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#highlevelconsumerapi) that can be used to solve this.

Also set option "auto.commit.enable" to "false" so that at no time, the offsets are committed automatically by kafka consumer.

Comment: Note that `auto.commit.enable` is deprecated for the high-level consumer API. You can use the global setting `enable.auto.commit` instead.